# Representation of cardiod in the complex plane

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I noticed that the complex function $$f(z) = \frac{2}{(z+i)^2}$$ seems to map the real line onto the [cardioid](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot%28x%3D%281-cos%28theta%29%29cos%28theta%29%2Cy%3D%281-cos%28theta%29%29sin%28theta%29%29) given by the polar equation: $$r = 1- \cos(\theta).$$
I was wondering if there is a simple explanation for this? I did note that, for $t \in \mathbb{R}$, one can write
$$f(t) = \frac{2}{(t+i)(t-i)} \cdot \frac{t-i}{t+i} = r(t) u(t)$$
where $r(t) = \frac{2}{t^2+1}$ maps $\mathbb{R} \to [0,2]$ and $u(t) = \frac{t-i}{t+i}$ is Cayley transform which maps $\mathbb{R}$ to the unit circle.

Is there an elegant way to continue from here?

Comment: Write $t = \cot \varphi$ and simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $t = \cot\varphi$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\frac{2}{t^2+1}\frac{t-i}{t+i} &= \frac{2}{\cot^2\varphi + 1}\frac{\cot\varphi - i}{\cot\varphi+i}\\
&= \frac{2\sin^2\varphi}{\cos^2\varphi+\sin^2\varphi}\frac{\cos\varphi - i\sin\varphi}{\cos\varphi + i\sin\varphi}\\
&= 2\sin^2\varphi \frac{e^{-i\varphi}}{e^{i\varphi}}\\
&= (1 - \cos (2\varphi))e^{-2i\varphi}.
\end{align}$$

Rename $\theta = -2\varphi$.

The simple explanation is that the inversion $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z+i}$ maps the real line to the circle $\lvert w + \frac{i}{2}\rvert = \frac{1}{2}$, and squaring maps circles passing through the origin to cardioids.

Comment: Nice going! I was in the midst of calculating the real and imaginary parts of $\frac{t+i}{t-i}$, but this is a much nicer way!